# Local Jenkins can't authenticate remote Gitlab private repository

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I installed Jenkins on windows with all addons that I need, I think so. When i create a new job and in Repository URL i write my url

`http://git.*****.org/*****/seleniumproject.git`

and it shows

```
Help for feature: Repository URL
Failed to connect to repository : Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe ls-remote -h http://git.*****.org/*****/seleniumproject.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://git.*****.org/*****/seleniumproject.git'`
```

**My question**: how can I authenticate to my remote gitlab?! I have folder with .ssh with all keys but don't know what to do...

**Update:** strange because my TortoiseGit is working perfectly

**My Fix :**

1. Go to jenkins path and save .ssh folder in root example
   `C:\Jenkins\.ssh` .ssh folder u can find in `C:\Users\yourname\.ssh`
2. Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Manage Credentials, here you can
   add your private key or select **from the jenkins master !/.ssh**
3. Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System in git executable wrote this `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe` path must be with **cmd**
4. Create new job and in repository url add
   `ssh://git@git.sitename.org:/name/projet.git`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**My Fix :**

1. Go to jenkins path and save .ssh folder in root example
   C:\Jenkins.ssh .ssh folder u can find in C:\Users\yourname.ssh
2. Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Manage Credentials, here you can
   add your private key or select from the jenkins master !/.ssh
3. Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System in git executable
   wrote this C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe path must be with
   cmd
4. Create new job and in repository url add
   ssh://git@git.sitename.org:/name/projet.git

Comment: Excellent feedback. +1. More accurate than [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18636384/6309)

Comment: Hello, I have 2 questions. What is `C:\Jenkins`? Home dir for Jenkins? What do you mean in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe path must be with cmd`? Where can I set it?

Answer (score 1):

> I have folder with .ssh with all keys

Those keys won't never been read, if you keep using an http(s) url.

You should use an ssh url, and first make sure that this works properly:

```
ssh -Tv ssh://git@git.*****.org
```

(assuming the user account you need on the server side is '`git`')

---

Note that the [section on SSH of this guide](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html#openssh-tortoisegit) is of interest here:

### you have installed TortoiseGIT

[image: http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows/git-ssh-variable.png]

> If you have ever installed TortoiseGit on the computer you’re setting up your keys on, you may encounter problems.
>   **TortiseGit creates an environment variable that configures Plink as your SSH keystore, which may conflict when you try to use Git and SSH**.
>   No matter how you change your config or uninstall TortoiseGit, that environment variable persists and until you delete it, Git will not look to your regular `.ssh` directory to find the proper key.
>
> In our case environment variable looked like this:

```
GIT_SSH=c:\Program Files\Putty\plink.exe.
```

> Environment variables can be found here:

- Windows XP: `Control Panel → System Properties → Advanced → Environment variables`
- Windows 7: `Control Panel → System → Advanced system settings → Environment variables`

Comment: Jenkins is sending url always with C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe ls-remote so i can't use -Tv because of this ls-remote

Comment: @AndrianDurlestean the `-Tv` is just for you to test ssh with the ssh `-Tv`. But once this is working, you don't need `-Tv` in your `ls-remote`.

Comment: i get: no address associated with name

Comment: ssh://git@git.****.org:9999/ my connection is with port =( i saw in my tortoisegit

Comment: Can you try: `ssh -Tv git@git.****.org:9999` (no `ssh://` and no final `/`)?

Comment: sad same problem =(, if Im trying with no port i get msg port 22: Bad file number, but my git server is with port 9999

Comment: @AndrianDurlestean I have edited my answer to address git in an environment where TortoiseGit was already there.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\gitk.cmd` instead of `\bin\git.exe`. If not solved, then [Here](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port) is information how to configure ssh. Sometimes you may also get public key error, which is solved [here](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey). If you want to generate new ssh keys, [this](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) article will help you.